# Wrapping JTextArea at fixed character width

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, word-wrap

I've been given two competing requirements for a Swing based TextArea component:

1. Must use a variable width font (because it looks pretty).
2. Must wrap text at a specific character width (to match a Text UI)

A simple to achieve combo, yes?  Hack a UI to supply my own version of a wrapped view, which inherits from WrappedPlainView, and override calculateBreakPosition() to provide the wrap behavior I want.

Except its not looking so simple.  Ignoring for the moment problems derived from variable render widths... I'm finding that calculateBreakPosition() is not being invoked for edits I'd expect to require its invocation (adding characters to the front of wrapped text), and it's calculating break positions off by 1 or 2 in some fairly common scenarios, without referring to my overridden method, leaving me to think I'm running into optimizations or details of the text area implementation I don't know enough about to expect.  Overriding more methods to debug and fix this is proving difficult: Many of the methods in WrappedPlainView are marked either final or private, contain references to com.sun classes, and/or reference private/final methods or methods using com.sun classes.

Any suggestions for getting this off the ground?

What I have currently:

```
package com.foo.inputs;

import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView;

public class CustomWrappedPlainView extends WrappedPlainView
{
    private int charsWide;

    public CustomWrappedPlainView(Element elem, int width)
    {
        super(elem, true);
        this.charsWide = width;
    }


    @Override    
    protected int calculateBreakPosition(int p0, int p1)
    {
        int length = p1 - p0; 
        // Check for fit without wrapping.
        if(length <= charsWide)
        {
            return p1;
        }

        // Given: Past this point, we have at least charsWide+1 characters.

        String text;
        try
        {
            // Get one extra character.  If wrapping at 5 chars and the/
            // first six chars are: '12345 '  then we don't need to split
            // anything - that extra char matters.
            text = getDocument().getText(p0, charsWide+1);
        } catch(BadLocationException err)
        {
            // Should not happen
            // Fall back to max width
            return p0 + charsWide; 
        }
        return p0 + getBreakPosition(text, charsWide);
    }


    /** Determine where to break a substring. */
    static protected int getBreakPosition(String text, int charsWide)
    {
        // Paranoid check to avoid string bound errors
        if(text.length() <= charsWide)
        {
            return text.length();
        }

        // keep this simple, until/unless we need something more complex.

        for(int i = charsWide; i>= 0; i--)
        {
            char nyble = text.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(nyble))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if(Character.isDigit(nyble))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if(Character.isWhitespace(nyble))
            {
                // Wrap AFTER the space.
                // Don't start new lines with a space.
                return i+1;
            }
        }
        // Fallback: wrap after our break point
        return charsWide;
    }

    /** 
     * Utility method for CustomTextAreaEditor.  Ultimately this must
     * match the break logic from {@link #calculateBreakPosition(int, int)}
     * exactly to allow for WYSIWYG.
     */
    public static String[] breakOutLines(String text, int wrapWidth)
    {
        String[] paragraphs = text.split("\n");
        Vector<String> lines = new Vector<>();
        nextParagraph:
        for(String paragraph : paragraphs)
        {
            int length = paragraph.length();
            while(length > 0)
            {
                if(length <= wrapWidth)
                {
                    lines.add(paragraph);
                    continue nextParagraph;
                }
                int breakPoint = getBreakPosition(paragraph, wrapWidth);
                lines.add(paragraph.substring(0,breakPoint));
                paragraph = paragraph.substring(breakPoint);
                length = paragraph.length();
            }
        }
        return lines.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will help but maybe instead of writing custom break logic you might be able to get away with playing with the FontMetrics:

```
@Override    
protected int calculateBreakPosition(int p0, int p1)
{
    FontMetrics original = metrics;
    FontMetrics monospacedFontMetrics = ...;

    int position = super.calculateBreakPosition(p0, p1);

    metrics = original;

    return position;
}
```

So you could create a Monospaced font the same size as the current Font and then use that font to get the FontMetrics to be used in the break calculation.

Or you may need to copy the code from the `calculateBreakPosition(...)` method so you can also override the `currentWidth` to be what you want.

Comment: Any feedback? Did this help?

Comment: Apologies, meant to get back to this earlier.  I suspect it won't work (my problem is that calculateBreakPosition() isn't being invoked, so overrides based on it are likely to fail), but I haven't had time to properly try it out.  Assuming it works, I'm faced then with requiring a fixed width component, in a UI Framework that won't permit it.  The other approaches I have involve sufficient hyjinks that they would probably fail on something in the details of JTextArea